# View isn't showing in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm trying to use mvvm design pattern. I searched and read many mvvm documents and examples, but it's really difficult to me.

I want navigate and show view from main window but my code isn't working.

Without `<Window.Resources> ~ </Window.Resources>` part, ContentControl elements shows text 'MyProject.ViewModel.AuthViewModel'.

but If i put  `<Window.Resources>` part, `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MyProject.Helper.DelegateCommand.CanExecute(Object parameter)` error occurs

What is wrong?

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ICommand _changeViewCommand;
    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
    private List<ViewModelBase> _viewModels;

    public MainViewModel(){
        ViewModels.Add(new AuthViewModel());
        CurrentViewModel = ViewModels[0];   
    }

    #region Commands
    public ICommand ChangeViewCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changeViewCommand == null)
            {
                _changeViewCommand = new DelegateCommand(
                    param => ChangeViewModel((ViewModelBase)param),
                    param => param is ViewModelBase
                );
            }
            return _changeViewCommand;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public List<ViewModelBase> ViewModels
    {
        get
        {
            if (_viewModels == null)
                _viewModels = new List<ViewModelBase>();

            return _viewModels;
        }
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_currentViewModel != value)
            {
                _currentViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void ChangeViewModel(ViewModelBase _viewModel)
    {
        if (_viewModel != null && !ViewModels.Contains(_viewModel))
            ViewModels.Add(_viewModel);

        CurrentViewModel = ViewModels.FirstOrDefault(_vm => _vm == _viewModel);
    }
```

**MainView.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProject.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel"
        xmlns:mp="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        Title="MyProject" Height="630" Width="460" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainViewViewModel}">
            <v:BeamView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AuthViewModel}">
            <v:AuthView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dayum. `<DateTemplate>` didn't cause this problem.

I just wrote wrong code at `DelegateCommand` class

```
public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter != null) // what the hell ?
        return true;
    return _canExecute(parameter);
}
```

and i fixed it

```
public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter == null)
        return true;
    return _canExecute(parameter);
}
```